# Wielders of Weapons

Tags: single-word-requests, history

I'm looking for what the various wielders of weapons called. I know of a few, but would like to know of the others below :

Bow and Arrow - Archer/Bowman

Sword - Swordsman (???)

Axe -

Club -

Dagger -

Flail -

Lance - Lancer (courtesy of @HotLicks)

Mace -

Pike - Pikeman (courtesy of @HotLicks)

Sling - Slinger (courtesy of @ab2)

Spear -

War Hammer -

Whip -

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Well, there were the "Bengal Lancers".

Comment: @HotLicks: :) well, does that mean, that I could make axer, clubber, flailer, macer, hammererers...etc ? That would be the easy way out...

Comment: Alas, no.  The naming of military skills/duties is quite idiosyncratic.  "Piker", for instance, means something entirely different.  (But I do find [pikeman](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pikeman).)

Comment: slinger -- the Balearic slingers were famous in antiquity https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=balearic+slingers

Comment: There's no guarantee that these 'agent' words are all filled out naturally. Sure you can use X-wielder, but it may not be natural sounding or, if natural, a set phrase. That is, you end up having ... make some up. _shudder_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my kind of question! I used to be interested in different kinds of weapons and wanted words for warriors wielding each type.

- Bow and arrow - [**archer**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/archer) or [**bowman**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bowman).
- Sword - [**swordsman**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/swordsman).
- Axe - [**axeman**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/axeman).
- Club - I'm not aware of a special word for this, but you could try simply **club wielder**.
- Dagger - [**knifeman**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/knifeman) or **knife fighter**.
- Flail - I never managed to find a good word; I used **flailer**, but others don't seem to.
- Lance - [**lancer**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lancer).
- Mace - again I'm not aware of a special word for this, so try **mace wielder** or **mace fighter**.
- Pike - [**pikeman**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pikeman).
- Sling - [**slinger**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/slinger)
- Spear - [**spearman**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/spearman).
- Warhammer - again I'm not aware of a special word, so try **hammer wielder** (or [Thor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thor) ;-) )
- Whip - [**whipman**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/whipman) or **whip wielder**.

Comment: Even though, 3 words are missing, I'm accepting this as it covers many of my required words. I will update as and when I find something new...

Answer (score 1):

Bow and Arrow - Archer/Bowman/ Mergen

Sword - Swordsman (???)/ Warrior/ Zenith/ Swordmaster/ Sword-Dancer

Axe - Berserker/ Barbarian/ Lumberjack

Club - Caveman/ Clubber/ Orge

Dagger - Thief/ Rogue/ Trickster

Flail - Wrecker/ Crusader(?)

Lance - Lancer (courtesy of @HotLicks)

Mace - Barbarian (too?)

Pike - Pikeman (courtesy of @HotLicks)

Sling - Slinger (courtesy of @ab2)

Spear - Spearman/ Tribeman

War Hammer - Paladin(?)

Whip - Torturer

Answer (score 0):

For a mace or a club, I could suggest 'brawler' or 'bludgeoner' since those don't actually seem to have specific terms.  There's 'bojutsu' in Japanese, which is roughly translated to 'staff art' and covers things like the kanabo, if that helps.

Comment: Peter, this would be better if you cited and linked to supporting information.